# Remote ssh is hanging on checking log and pid in VSCode-Server

Tags: remote-server, vscode-remote

After downloading VSCode-Server, the remote SSH is hanging on checking log and pid which does not exist at the remote server.

```txt
65a78c9b5eba: running
Acquiring lock on /root/.vscode-server/bin/379476f0e13988d90fab105c5c19e7abc8b1dea8/
vscode-remote-lock.root.379476f0e13988d90fab105c5c19e7abc8b1dea8
Found existing installation at /root/.vscode-server/bin/379476f0e13988d90fab105c5c19e7abc8b1dea8...   
Checking /root/.vscode-server/.379476f0e13988d90fab105c5c19e7abc8b1dea8.log
and /root/.vscode-server/.379476f0e13988d90fab105c5c19e7abc8b1dea8.pid for a running server
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and creating the two files that are checked did the trick, i.e. in your case:

```
touch /root/.vscode-server/.379476f0e13988d90fab105c5c19e7abc8b1dea8.log
touch /root/.vscode-server/.379476f0e13988d90fab105c5c19e7abc8b1dea8.pid
```